# Where does the business logic go on the parse server when building an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, parse-platform

I am a beginner to the Parse Server, the documentation is great for reading saving and deleting information from a database, but I have yet to see an example that demonstrate where the business logic go on a real API.

Answer (score 0):

Parse server is a mobile backend as a service (MBaaS) which means it provides the *API* for you to build the client apps easily without taking the hassle of developing and maintaining backend codes. You can use parse's rest API or client libraries (android, iOS, JS and so on..) to build an app.

If you are planning to write your own backend API with parse-server then you can do it just like any other express applications.

Answer (score 0):

It seems business logic is supposed to be included in cloud code, on the rest api guide it reads:

> Implementing Business Logic in Cloud Code
>
> While validation often makes sense in Cloud Code, there are likely certain actions that are particularly sensitive, and should be as carefully guarded as possible. In these cases, you can remove permissions or the logic from clients entirely and instead funnel all such operations to Cloud Code functions.

[Parse server REST Guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#implementing-business-logic-in-cloud-code)

Comment: Yes Cloud Code is a great tool to customize and add your logic to Parse Server. Triggers and custom functions will give you great ability.